# ARM Template redeploy is broken

Tags: azure, templates, deployment

This is actually about REDEPLOYing an ARM template with a new scale set but all other resources are the same as they were. This used to work and its now been broken by Microsoft Azure. Have redeployed a template many hundreds of times. This exact same template.

1. Go to the Resource Group you deployed with the ARM template.
2. Under 'Deploments' there will be a link to the template blade. Click
   on it and then click on the template
3. At the top of the blade is a redeploy button. Click on it.
4. Select the current existing Resource Group. Enter all other
   parameters the same as the original deployment.
5. Agree to the terms and conditions
6. Click purchase and there will be validation errors shown.
7. Click to see the error details. They are all about resources already existing. This used to not occur - sensibly and thus a template could be redeployed.

Here is a link to the template in question, but its not template specific. All templates now fail to re-deploy. http://docs.lansa.com/14/en/Lansa022/index.htm#lansa/vldtoolct_0330.htm#VLDToolCT_0330 The particular resource group that I used to repo this has already been deleted.

Its easy to repro.

ps I created a new VM in a Resource Group using the standard Azure Windows Server 2012 Datacenter image, and it too cannot be re-deployed due to the same errors.

Comment: does it work for you now? i think it does work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this using Powershell or Azure Cli or any other template deployment technique (both modes work, complete and incremental), it appears it only affects the portal.

As of 18.02 everything seems to be back to normal.

Comment: Thank you, for the workarounds. So you can confirm that this behavior has changed? The portal used to allow a Deployment to be re-deployed

Comment: I think yes, I'm not sure, but I think it did work before.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed in the portal. It was fixed on about 17th February.